# Cannot Fetch or use any git commands (push , pull , ...) on Atlassian BitBucket Repository

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

When i try to fetch or do any command on my Atlassian gitbucket i get the following error
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/39pZ7.png)

Anyone could help, please ?
Thank you in advance for your help, it will be a life saver

I tried to fetch on BitBucket Repository

Comment: Please add the error message as text to your question directly. Linking a picture on an external resource is bad practice.

Comment: I agree about not posting images of text - just paste the text! - but you should also check out https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/mn08j05ms7wx and see if you're able to fetch (etc.) again.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your help and I apologize for not posting directly the text .
However, it was about an issue on Atlassian BitBucket Server i think and it was resolved right away.